# PYROCMS display custom image fields in page body

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

pyrocms page in Body Editor how to code for display custom fields data. like

i have a image custom field. i write code like.

> {{ image:id }}
>
> {{ page:image:id }}
>
> {{ pages:image:id }}
>
> {{ template:image:id }}

```
{{ custom_fields }} 
     <img alt="" class="img-custom-responsive img-border" data-pyroimage="true" src="{{ url:site }}files/thumb/{{ image:id }}/310/310/fit" /> 
{{ /custom_fields }}
```

i write this code in **body Editor** But this is not return image id.

How can i get image id on body Editor.

please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read through the documentation? https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation

Comment: yes i can't find help in document.

Comment: Your image custom field slug is `image` exactly?

Comment: ya. i check my slug is image.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "id" attribute for the image field type.
Check out [the docs on the image field-type](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/field-types/image) to see the available attributes.

Example:

`{{ custom_fields }}{{ image:img }}{{ /custom_fields }} // produces a full img tag`

`{{ custom_fields }}{{ image:filename }}{{ /custom_fields }} // get the filename`